# Auto adjust height Accordion In the New Google Sites

Tags: javascript, accordion, google-sites

Beginner here. The accordion submenu height display differently in the New Google Sites than other sites. Does it not support Accordion?

I copied an accordion code from [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SteliosBox/pen/VzPMKy/) `enter code here`and made changes in [w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G64YH3L0HIET).

It turns out well in w3School. But when I copy the code and paste it to the New Google Sites, the height of the accordion stretched longer and was not auto adjusted.

Anyone can help me so that the Google Sites can display like the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this video which has examples on Accordian using bootstrap. 
https://youtu.be/1Ny-1zHw5AI?t=751

Other than that, you can also check out this [fiddle by Elvis](https://jsfiddle.net/esedic/oza6v6px) which you can fork to customize per your need. And after customization, you can embed the result in your New Google-Site.

```
$(".panel-heading").parent('.panel').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).children('.collapse').collapse('show');
  }, function() {
    $(this).children('.collapse').collapse('hide');
  }
);
```